# Gitlab Api Commits Behind/Ahead Master

Tags: python, api, gitlab, gitlab-api, python-gitlab

On the Gitlab webpage you have the possibility to check how many commits a branch is behind or ahead of the master branch.
My question is if it is possible to get information about this with the "gitlab API"? I checked the docs but unfortunately couldn't find anything.

Comment: As in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51572162/6309?

Comment: @VonC i am searching for Gitlab API and not Github

Answer (score 1):

The specific Gitlab API that does the trick is

```
GET /projects/:id/repository/compare
```

More info at https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/repositories.html#compare-branches-tags-or-commits

Execution example to bring you number of commits that differentiates the 2 branches

```
curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <access_token>" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/repository/compare?from=<branch_name_behind_in_commits>&to=<branch_name_ahead_in_commits>&straight=true" | jq '. | .commits | length'
```

1. If you want to see how many commits is `master` branch
   `behind` of `feature` branch. You should add the master to `from` field
   and feature branch at `to` field
2. If you want to see how many commits is `master` branch
   `ahead` of `feature` branch. You should add the feature branch to `from` field
   and master branch at `to` field

Answer (score 0):

Look for include_diverged_commits_count: "true" (default is false) in the MR API: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/merge_requests.html#get-single-mr.

The only downer (IMHO) is that this seems to be only available via the MR API, and so you need to first create a MR.